# Symfony2 / File Upload - guessExtension on null if file field is empty

Tags: php, symfony, upload

I have file field with required = false, multiple=multiple. Everything works fine, but if file input is empty, symfony2 show me this error.

`Error: Call to a member function guessExtension() on null`

Here is my form type:

```
->add('file', 'file', array(
                'multiple' => 'multiple',
                'data_class' => null,
                'required' => false,
                'mapped' => false,
                'attr' => array(
                    'maxSize' => '1024k',
                    'accept' => 'image/*',
                )
            ))
```

Upload function:

```
private function uploadImg($files)
    {
        $path = array();
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $extension = $file->guessExtension();
            if (!$extension) {
                $extension = 'bin';
            }
            $randomName = 'image' . date('Y-m-d-H-i-s') . uniqid() . '.' . $extension;
            $file->move('uploads/images/', $randomName);
            $path[] = $randomName;
        }
        return $path;
    }
```

How can I check if file input is empty?

`$form['file']->getData();` every time returns `Array`

Comment: You can try with `count`. Since `multiple` is set to `true` you will always end up receiving an array, whether it's empty or not.

Comment: Thanks, but it works only if input is totally empty or has 2 or more files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `continue` to skip empty files

```
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if(!$file) {
            continue; //skip
        }

        $extension = $file->guessExtension();
        if (!$extension) {
            $extension = 'bin';
        }
        $randomName = 'image' . date('Y-m-d-H-i-s') . uniqid() . '.' . $extension;
        $file->move('uploads/images/', $randomName);
        $path[] = $randomName;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Symfony 3, I used this method and working fine.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

public function updateAction(...){
  // $image is Entity property, change accordingly.
  $file = $item->getImage();
  if ($file instanceof UploadedFile) {
     ... upload code
  }
}
```